# qt - QAbstractItemView and [vertical/horizontal]ScrollMode

Tags: qt, scroll, qlistview

QAbstractItemView features setters/getters for vertical and horizontal scroll model. possible values are: `ScrollPerItem` and `ScrollPerPixel`.

I'm using QListView with a custom model. The problem is that changing vertical scroll mode does not affect the way the contents are scrolled. The view is in `QListView::IconMode`. It appears that the scrolling is done per pixel. But because of mouse wheel clicks it actually scrolls per fixed pixel batches, which do not depend on the size of the items - even in the ScrollPerItem mode.

I need to scroll per item - each wheel click should scroll to the next row of items no matter what the size of the item is. Is it possible with default QListView implementation?